# Haskell "collections" language design

Tags: collections, haskell, language-design

Why is the Haskell implementation so focused on linked lists?

For example, I know Data.Sequence is more efficient
with most of the list operations (except for the `cons` operation), and is used a lot;
syntactically, though, it is "hardly supported". Haskell has put a lot of effort into functional abstractions, such as the Functor and the Foldable class, but their syntax is not compatible with that of the default list.

If, in a project I want to optimize and replace my lists with sequences - or if I suddenly want support for infinite collections, and replace my sequences with lists - the resulting code changes are abhorrent.

So I guess my wondering can be made concrete in questions such as:

1. Why isn't the type of `map` equal to `(Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`?
2. Why can't the `[]` and `(:)` functions be used for, for example, the type in Data.Sequence?

I am really hoping there is some explanation for this, that doesn't include the words "backwards compatibility" or "it just grew that way", though if you think there isn't, please let me know. Any relevant language extensions are welcome as well.

Comment: What do you mean by #2?  I can think of two sensible interpretations: (a) "Why can't the existing `:` and `[]` be made to have a more polymorphic type?"; (b) "Why are `:` and `[]` used for `Prelude.[]` *instead* of `Data.Sequence.Seq`?".

Comment: "it just grew that way" is pretty close.

Comment: @Antal: my question was (a), as I wanted to know why these functions/constructors were not more polymorphic. My reasoning was that the actual datatype used could be inferred from the typing (e.g., using `List a` or `Seq a`) and could default to the list.

Comment: I suspect that what you're really hoping for is something like GHC's [OverloadedStrings extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings), but applied to list literals instead of strings. Unfortunately, not only does this not exist, it doesn't even seem to have been suggested anywhere I can find...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before getting into why, here's a summary of the problem and what you can do about it.  The constructors `[]` and `(:)` are reserved for lists and cannot be redefined.  If you plan to use the same code with multiple data types, then define or choose a type class representing the interface you want to support, and use methods from that class.
Here are some generalized functions that work on both lists and sequences.  I don't know of a generalization of `(:)`, but you could write your own.

- `fmap` instead of `map`
- `mempty` instead of `[]`
- `mappend` instead of `(++)`

If you plan to do a one-off data type replacement, then you can define your own names for things, and redefine them later.

```
-- For now, use lists
type List a = [a]
nil = []
cons x xs = x : xs

{- Switch to Seq in the future
-- type List a = Seq a
-- nil = empty
-- cons x xs = x <| xs
-}
```

Note that `[]` and `(:)` are constructors: you can also use them for pattern matching.  Pattern matching is specific to one type constructor, so you can't extend a pattern to work on a new data type without rewriting the pattern-matchign code.

---

#### Why there's so much list-specific stuff in Haskell

Lists are commonly used to represent sequential *computations*, rather than data.  In an imperative language, you might build a Set with a loop that creates elements and inserts them into the set one by one.  In Haskell, you do the same thing by creating a list and then passing the list to `Set.fromList`.  Since lists so closely match this abstraction of computation, they have a place that's unlikely to ever be superseded by another data structure.

The fact remains that some functions are list-specific when they could have been generic.  Some common functions like `map` were made list-specific so that new users would have less to learn.  In particular, they provide simpler and (it was decided) more understandable error messages.  Since it's possible to use generic functions instead, the problem is really just a syntactic inconvenience.  It's worth noting that Haskell language *implementations* have very little list-speficic code, so new data structures and methods can be just as efficient as the "built-in" ones.

There are several classes that are useful generalizations of lists:

- **Functor** supplies `fmap`, a generalization of `map`.
- **Monoid** supplies methods useful for collections with list-like structure.  The empty list `[]` is generalized to other containers by `mempty`, and list concatenation `(++)` is generalized to other containers by `mappend`.
- **Applicative** and **Monad** supply methods that are useful for interpreting collections as computations.
- **Traversable** and **Foldable** supply useful methods for running computations over collections.

Of these, only Functor and Monad were in the influential Haskell 98 spec, so the others have been overlooked to varying degrees by library writers, depending on when the library was written and how actively it was maintained.  The core libraries have been good about supporting new interfaces.

Comment: Though I agree that it would increase the already steep learning curve of Haskell, shouldn't there be a way to even this out _after_ learning the basics? Isn't there a `Prelude` (or shouldn't there be) that fixes all these list-only functions to their generic counterparts?

Comment: @Pepijn: You don't have to use the Prelude, just put `import Prelude ()` in your code. For most of my hobby/experimental Haskell programming I use a modified Prelude that, among other things, replaces the list functions Heatsink mentions with their generic equivalents. For more drastic changes (e.g., replacing `Monad` for desugaring `do` notation) there's also GHC's NoImplicitPrelude extension.

Comment: This still makes me wonder: is there any way I can redefine the behavior of the `[]` constructur, and maybe the `[x, y, z]` notation?

Comment: @Pepijn: No, even if you hide the Prelude definitions, you can't redefine that syntax.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [short cut fusion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion), an optimization that, to oversimplify, takes a list producer and list consumer and sticks them together to bypass the overhead of constructing list items.  This helps make the idea of lists abstracting sequential computations a reality, as far as performance goes.

Comment: did you mean *passing the list to `Set.fromList`* instead?

Answer (score 7):

I remember reading somewhere that `map` is for lists by default since newcomers to Haskell would be put off if they made a mistake and saw a complex error about "Functors", which they have no idea about. Therefore, they have both `map` and `fmap` instead of just `map`.

EDIT: That "somewhere" is the Monad Reader Issue 13, page 20, footnote 3:

> 3You might ask why we need a separate map function. Why not just do away with the current
>   list-only map function, and rename fmap to map instead? Well, that’s a good question. The
>   usual argument is that someone just learning Haskell, when using map incorrectly, would much
>   rather see an error about lists than about Functors.

For `(:)`, the `(<|)` function seems to be a replacement. I have no idea about `[]`.

Comment: What about `Data.Sequence.empty`? Or `Control.Monad.mempty`? They should do.

Answer (score 5):

A nitpick, Data.Sequence isn't more efficient for "list operations", it is more efficient for sequence operations. That said, a lot of the functions in Data.List are really sequence operations. The finger tree inside Data.Sequence has to do quite a bit more work for a cons (<|) equivalent to list (:), and its memory representation is also somewhat larger than a list as it is made from two data types a FingerTree and a Deep.

The extra syntax for lists is fine, it hits the sweet spot at what lists are good at - cons (:) and pattern-matching from the left. Whether or not sequences should have extra syntax is further debate, but as you can get a very long way with lists, and lists are inherently simple, having good syntax is a must.

List isn't an ideal representation for Strings - the memory layout is inefficient as each Char is wrapped with a constructor. This is why ByteStrings were introduced. Although they are laid out as an array ByteStrings have to do a bit of administrative work - [Char] can still be competitive if you are using short strings. In GHC there are language extensions to give ByteStrings more String-like syntax.

The other major lazy functional Clean has always represented strings as byte arrays, but its type system made this more practical - I believe the ByteString library uses unsafePerfomIO under the hood.

Comment: It's not lazy, but ML (at least what I've used) also treats strings as atoms, not lists.

Comment: Having `Data.ByteString` and `Data.Text`, I don't see any reason to keep using the inefficient `[Char]`.  The problem is that there is nothing AFAIK that unifies `[Char]` , `Data.ByteString` and `Data.Text` .  We see `String` everywhere in APIs, because it's simple/pedagogical/dependency-less.  Shouldn't we use some kind of `StringLike` class instead?  This would remove the need to use `pack` and `unpack` to adapt to APIs using plain-old `String`.

Comment: @gawi. [Char] isn't always inefficient though. As I said in the message if you have short strings it can out-perform ByteStrings for some use-cases. If you got rid of [Char] people would want it re-introducing again (including me as I use short strings far more often than long ones).

Comment: @stephen Not getting rid of it, but not forcing everyone to use it.  Use a typeclass instead.

Comment: @gawi: this is a bit off topic, but what functions would be defined by the `String` typeclass? as a simple `toCharList` function would mostly defeat the purpose, and make working with instances of String really awkward...

Comment: @Pepijn: Most of the functions we see both in ByteString and Text could be in the `StringLike` typeclass. The `toCharList` function could be used as a last resort when typeclass-supplied functions would not provide the required functionality.

Answer (score 4):

With version 7.8, ghc supports overloading list literals, compare the [manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-lists). For example, given appropriate `IsList` instances, you can write

```
['0' .. '9']             :: Set Char
[1 .. 10]                :: Vector Int
[("default",0), (k1,v1)] :: Map String Int
['a' .. 'z']             :: Text
```

(quoted from the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this won't be an answer to your question, but still.

I wish Haskell had more liberal function names(mixfix!) [a la Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ReferenceManual.Mixfix). Then, the syntax for list constructors (`:`,`[]`) wouldn't have been *magic*; allowing us to at least hide the list type and use the same tokens for our own types.

The amount of code change while migrating between list and custom sequence types would be minimal then.

About `map`, you are a bit luckier. You can always hide map, and set it equal to fmap yourself.

```
import Prelude hiding(map)

map :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
map = fmap
```

Prelude is great, but it isn't the best part of Haskell.

Comment: This indeed isn't an answer to my question, but it's more of a clarification; I am aware I can hide `map`, and and set it equal to `fmap`. My question was, why do I have to? (This is answered sufficiently above though.)