# A question concerning list accesses from a noobie functional programmer

Tags: data-structures, haskell, programming-languages, functional-programming, ocaml

This might be a silly and obvious question, but why are list access algorithm examples implemented in linear time? I understand that most applications involve traversing lists rather than accessing them randomly, but what if you want to perform an access on a list with random accesses?

Comment: If you're talking about functional programming examples, I guess it's because functional programming most naturally uses recursion?

Comment: There are lots of data structures and a common newbie mistake is to try and use lists in cases they perform poorly.  I suggest you also learn about Haskells [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers), [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers), and [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) packages as a start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because lists are by design a linear structure. They are the canonical recursive data type, defined as:

```
 data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

That is, either the empty list, or a cons node, consisting of an element, and a tail, which is also a list.

This structure precisely corresponds to inductive definitions in mathematics, and correspondingly, makes it trivial to write many functions as simple recursive calls.

The recursive data type does not admit random access in non-linear time, however. For that you need hardware support (which we all have), and a more sophisticated data type (or less sophisticated, depending on your viewpoint).

*Summary*: lists are computer science's encoding of induction as a recursive data structure. It's fundamental, you need it, but it doesn't do random access.

Comment: In the Java world, `java.util.List` is an interface (i.e. it's abstract), which is implemented both by a linked list class and an array-backed list class. That might be the source of the confusion, for some people.

Comment: « lists are computer science's encoding of induction as a recursive data structure ». I can't make any sense of this. Other algebraic data structures are also inductive. This doesn't justify why list would be any more "fundamental". I think lists are widely used because we often need to manipulate an unbound number of elements of a type, but your formulation makes it look like there is a deeper reason, while there really isn't.

Comment: @gasche - would you consider the natural numbers as "fundamental"? Lists are just the natural numbers carrying a data item at each element. `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` cf. `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`.

Comment: @stephen tetley > why would the *unary* representation of natural numbers be more fundamental than, say, the binary one? Okasaki knows how to build structures from them also.

Comment: @gasche - unary is simpler, hence more "fundamental". Okasaki starts chapter 9 with the analogy I repeated above, as a prelude to the more complicated binary case.

Comment: I don't want to sound pedantic, but "simpler" and "fundamental" are different concepts. Lists are indeed a "simple" inductive structure (at least among the recursive parametrized ones), but that alone does not make it more "fundamental" than any other.

Comment: Well - List is the most essential inductive data structure - there's the base case Nil and the single recursive case Cons labelled with one datum. Neither case has any extra annotation unlike Okasaki's binary list (page 120), thus I'm quite happy to consider List the fundamental inductive data structure - there really is nothing there but the minimum. "Fundamental" isn't synonymous with "simpler" but nor is it synonymous with "generative", List can be fundamental even though you can't generate Binary lists, trees etc. from its definition.

Comment: @gasche: One explanation I've seen, [in this related SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180822/haskell-collections-language-design/4181251#4181251), for why lists are so fundamental is that they often represent *sequential computation*, rather than simply data.

Answer (score 9):

Haskell lists correspond to linked lists in imperative languages; they are inherently sequential since you only have access to the head and need to traverse to find other elements.

If you want random access you should choose some other data type.  Perhaps from Data.Array or Data.IntMap.